# How to solve SnackBar did not work and black screen in flutter after add StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am doing login and sign up using firebase. I have two error. First is the error message from firebase that did not show at the snack bar. The second is after I add StreamBuilder my apps become black screen.
Does anyone know how to solve this question? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:
Main.dart

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
          if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
            return HomePage();
          }
          return AuthScreen();
        }),
  );
}
}
```

AuthScreen.dart

```
    class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var _isLoading = false;

  void _submitAuthForm(
    String email,
    String password,
    String username,
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx,
  ) async {
    UserCredential authResult;

    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      if (isLogin) {
        authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } else {
        authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(authResult.user.uid)
            .set({
          'username': username,
          'email': email,
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      var message = 'An error occurred, pelase check your credentials!';

      if (err.message != null) {
        message = err.message;
      }

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(message),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
        ),
      );
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: AuthForm(
        _submitAuthForm,
        _isLoading,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Auth_form.dart

```
    class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  AuthForm(
    this.submitFn,
    this.isLoading,
  );

  final bool isLoading;
  final void Function(
    String email,
    String password,
    String userName,
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx,
  ) submitFn;

  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _isLogin = true;
  var _userEmail = '';
  var _userName = '';
  var _userPassword = '';

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      widget.submitFn(_userEmail.trim(), _userPassword.trim(), _userName.trim(),
          _isLogin, context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email address',
                    ),
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userEmail = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  if (!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('username'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                          return 'Please enter at least 4 characters';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userName = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be at least 7 characters long.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userPassword = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 12),
                  if (widget.isLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Signup'),
                      onPressed: _trySubmit,
                    ),
                  if (!widget.isLoading)
                    FlatButton(
                      textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      child: Text(_isLogin
                          ? 'Create new account'
                          : 'I already have an account'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Add code for home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a `SnackBar` first define a `key`:

`final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();`

Then, add a `ScaffoldMessenger` to your widget tree:

```
ScaffoldMessenger(
 key: key, // assign the key property to your previously created key
 child: Scaffold(...),
)
```

Now you can show the `SnackBar`:

`key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(...))`

Please add code for your home page, so we can inspect it and see why it shows a black screen, you probably forgot to wrap it in a `Scaffold`. You should return a `Scaffold` in the home page and the black screen will go away.

Comment: hi @Andrej, thank you for your reply. I have try but still did not show the message

Comment: Are you getting any error? You should return a Scaffold in the home page and the black screen will go away.

Comment: Can already. Just now I did not return Scaffold. Thank You

Comment: No problem, have a nice day :)